# Finding max values of array 12 elements at a time

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, max

I have an array that has around 1000 entries, these are split up into 12 entries per year, I'm trying to find the maximum value for each year, to do so I need to read 12 values at a time and find the maximum value of those 12, and then move on to the next 12 values from the array, and so on until it is complete.

Trying to do this I made a temporary array to store the 12 values in, as well as the final array with the max score per year. The code below doesn't work and i'm unsure why, I have spent quite a while researching and attempting this with different solutions, any help will be appreciated :)

```
//double rain[]= new double [1268];  this is the array declared earlier with data in

double maxRAINyear[]= new double [1200];
double temp [] = new double [12];
int arrayCounter = 0;
int count = 0;
for (int c = 36; c < rain.length; c++) {
   temp[count] = rain[c];
   if (count == 12){
       Arrays.sort(temp);
       double max = temp[temp.length - 1];
       maxRAINyear[arrayCounter] = max;
       arrayCounter++;
       count = 0;
   }
   count++;

}
```

Comment: And from whre cames the 36 value for C ?

Comment: mistype, it is supposed to be 12, the 36 value is because the first 36 values are all 0's and are unneeded for this part of the program.

Comment: In what way it doesn't work? Does it throw an exception or produce incorrect output?

Comment: Might it be more efficient to use a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Double>>`? This way you can separate your monthly amounts of rain out by year and address each year's ArrayList directly, and your code will be much easier to read than what you've shown us.

Comment: You know you could search the max yourself easier without needing a temp array then sorting it ? You are already iterating the array, simply search the max value and reset the tmp integer every 12 iteration.

Comment: @Eran The outputs are all 0's, I checked the array and the data is going into it, the process of finding the max is wrong i think

Comment: I believe you should have `count++` before the `if` statement.

Comment: 1268 months, that’s 210 years 8 months? Just checking.

Comment: @OleV.V. 1268 / 12 = 105 years, 6 months

Comment: You’re a lot closer than I am, sorry about my division skills. I think your remaining months (whether they are 6 or 8) require some special treatment in your code.

Comment: @Jamie you can check my working function. It is not the best but it will work just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented it without a temporary array, but by just iterating over the array. That should be more efficient.

```
    int amountOfYears = rain.length/12-3;
    double maxRAINyear[]= new double [amountOfYears];
    for(int i=0;i<amountOfYears;i++){

        //Find maximum for these 12 indixes
        double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        for(int j=12*i+36;j<12*(i+1)+36;j++){ //use 12*i as an offset, that way, you don't need a temp array
            if(rain[j] > max)
                max = rain[j];
        }
        //store maximum
        maxRAINyear[i] = max;

    }
```

If you also need to find the partial year, use this

```
    int amountOfYears = Math.ceil(rain.length/12f)-3;
    double maxRAINyear[]= new double [amountOfYears];
    for(int i=0;i<amountOfYears;i++){

        //Find maximum for these 12 indixes
        double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        int start = 12*i+36;
        int end = Math.min(rain.length,12*(i+1)+36);
        for(int j=start;j<end;j++){ //use 12*i as an offset, that way, you don't need a temp array
            if(rain[j] > max)
                max = rain[j];
        }
        //store maximum
        maxRAINyear[i] = max;

    }
```

Comment: That unecessaray complicated ;) see [gandaliter answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43915713/4391450)

Comment: @Jamie the implementation is over complicated

Comment: Also, I don't think you're going to get the partial year at the end

Comment: @gandaliter it will because of `int amountOfYears = rain.length/12-3;`, it will loose the decimal part of the division (the partial year).

Comment: ah, okay, how would you adapt it to find the minimum value?

Comment: initialize max to Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY (but perhaps rename it to min) and then in the check replace if(rain[j] > max) to if(rain[j] < min)

Comment: @ThijsSteel you don't get the problem. You array will not be long enough, if you have 14 month to check, you array will have a length of 1 (well without take in account the 36 first month skipped). So you will not read the 2 last month for the partial (current ? ) year. EDIT : My bad, not answering the comment I though ^^

Comment: @AxelH, my bad, it though he wanted the minimum now. And as for the partial year problem. I assumed that those should not be included (as the original question mentioned only groups of twelve) but it's fixed now

Comment: @ThijsSteel `Math.round` will not round like you want. You want to use `Math.ceil` to get the next integer. Round will take the closest integer

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to see what's wrong with your code without knowing what it produces, but in any case this isn't a great way to do this.

I'll assume that you are constrained to the input format of one long array, even though a multidimensional array might make more sense depending on what else it's used for.

```
// double rain[] = new double[1268]; // input
double maxRAINyear[] = new double[(rain.length+11) / 12];
double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
for (int i = 0; i < rain.length; i++)
{
    if (rain[i] > max) max = rain[i];
    if (i % 12 == 0)
    {
        maxRAINyear[i / 12] = max;
        max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    }
}
if (rain.length % 12 != 0) maxRAINyear[maxRAINyear.length-1] = max;
```

This calculates the maximum of each 12 numbers as it goes, rather than storing them separately and sorting them. I've assumed there are a whole number of years stored. If you want to account for a partial year at the end this will need to be modified.

Comment: It does end on a partial year, on the 5th month to be exact, how would I account for this?

Comment: Depends what you want to do with it. As it is I think the partial year is just ignored. If you'd like to take the maximum from it anyway you'll need to increase the array length by one in that case, and then put the value of max after the loop ends into that last slot.

Comment: you can add a special case, where if(i == rain.length -1 && i%12 != 0) you do maxRAINyear[i/12+1] = max

Comment: I've edited to include this. I prefer not to do an extra check in the loop but add it afterwards, as it seems neater to me, but you could do it in the loop.

Comment: The outputs from this are a little out, the expected outputs for the first 3 max values are, 119.1, 156.7, 112.6. The actual outputs are; 123.9,149.9
and 145.8

Comment: The outputs are for 80 years worth of data, where there is 105 years of data

Comment: In your original code you start at 36. I wonder if that might have something to do with it. What does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

When `count` is 11, you are incrementing it to 12 and going into the next round of the loop. Now `temp[count] = rain[c];` will attempt to store a value into index 12 of `temp`, but there are only 12 entries with indices 0 through 11. So I suspect you are getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I believe you should move `count++` before the `if` statement. This way a count of 12 will be reset to 0 before it creates any havoc.

Answer (score 0):

This solution have the advantage to work if the array length is not a multiple of the range without doing to many check.

```
public static double[] read(double[] array, int range) { 
    double[] result = new double[array.length / range + (array.length % range > 0 ? 1 : 0 )]; //Just add one cell if the length is not a multiple of the range


    double max = array[0];
    int i = 1;
    while (i < array.length) {
        if (i % range == 0) { //Next range
            result[i / range - 1] = max; //Save last
            max = array[i]; //Get current
        } else if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
        }
        ++i;
    }
    result[result.length - 1] = max; //for the last range
    return result;
}
```